# Getting ValueError: character U+380031 is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff] when attempting connection to teradata using sqlalchemy in flask web app

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, odbc, teradata

I am getting the ValueError: character U+380031 is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff] when attempting to make a connection to teradata using sqlalchemy inside a flask web app.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
user = 'user_string'
pasw='password_string'
host = 'host_string'

td_engine = create_engine('teradata://'+ user +':' + pasw + '@'+ host + '/' + '?authentication=LDAP&driver=Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20')

sql = 'select * from dbc.usersV'
result = td_engine.execute(sql)
```

**I have been able to make a successful connection using pyodbc, however, I really would like to use sqlalchemy to accomplish this.**

The expected result is of course a successful teradata connection and the ability to return the result of 'select * from dbc.usersV'. However, I continue to get the ValueError: character U+380031 is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Seems to be an encoding issue. Maybe try adding `&characterset=UTF8` to your connection string?

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much. @Fred